# How do I keep UI changes after swiping to refresh in Android

Tags: java, android

So, I have this `getView` method in my `CommentsAdapter` class, and it basically allows the user to upvote or downvote a comment in the comments section while displaying the upvote count. I am able to upvote (and undo the upvote) with the corresponding UI change (blue button for un-upvoted and orange for upvoted).

However, once I refresh the screen, the button will always revert to blue regardless if it was upvoted or not and the vote count back to the original count. I did check the database and the correct upvote count and action were logged. Any tips?

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> { 
  private int layout;
  private Context context;
  private ArrayList<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();

  public CommentAdapter(@NonNull Context cont, @LayoutRes int textViewResourceId, @NonNull ArrayList<Post> objects) {
    super(cont, textViewResourceId, objects);
    layout = textViewResourceId;
    context = cont;
    postList = objects;
  }

  public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
      final ViewHolder v;
      final Post comment = postList.get(position);
      final String mimeType = "text/html";
      final String encoding = "UTF-8";
      final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("user_session", MODE_PRIVATE);
      final String sessionKey = prefs.getString("session_key", "");
      String htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"comments.css\" />" + comment.content;

      if (convertView == null) {
          v = new ViewHolder();
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

          v.upvotedIcon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_upvoted_icon);
          v.upvoteIcon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_upvote_icon);
          v.upvotedText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_upvoted_text);
          v.upvoteText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_upvote_text);

          v.upvoteButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_upvote_button);
          v.upvotedButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_upvoted_button);

          v.upvotedIcon.setTypeface(fontAwesome);
          v.upvoteIcon.setTypeface(fontAwesome);
          v.upvotedText.setTypeface(opensans);
          v.upvoteText.setTypeface(opensans);

          convertView.setTag(v);
      } else {
          v = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

      v.upvoteText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", comment.stats.upvotes));
      v.upvotedText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", comment.stats.upvotes + 1));

      if (comment.hasReacted) {
          v.upvoteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          v.upvotedButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
          v.upvotedButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          v.upvoteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      v.upvoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              setButtonState(true, comment, v);
              Call<JsonObject> call = MyApi.endpoint().upVotePost(sessionKey, comment.id);
              call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                      if(response.code() != 200) {
                          // show upvote icon
                          setButtonState(false, comment, v);
                          Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot upvote for the moment, try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                      // show upvote icon
                      setButtonState(false, comment, v);
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot connect to the server, try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
          }


      });

      v.upvotedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              // show upvote icon
              setButtonState(false, comment, v);
              Call<JsonObject> call = MyApi.endpoint().downVotePost(sessionKey, comment.id);
              call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                      if(response.code() != 200) {
                          // show upvoted icon
                          setButtonState(true, comment, v);
                          Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot undo your upvote for the moment, try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                      // show upvoted icon
                      setButtonState(true, comment, v);
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot connect to the server, try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
          }
      });

      return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you use `notifyDataSetChanged();` in your code?

Comment: @KeLiuyue How can I do that for this class? `CommentsAdapter` extends `ArrayAdapter` btw.

Comment: Can you please add the code, how you've initialized your adapter with the `postList`?

Comment: You can use `notifyDataSetChanged();` after the `setButtonState()` method.

Comment: @ReazMurshed, hi, please see the updated code

Comment: So where are you changing your database and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a property to your model that is a status, with values like "upvoted", "downvoted", etc., or {empty string}. Then when your data is acted on set that status accordingly. Then when the data is reloaded check your model for that status and display using the proper icon for each status. (I am simply using strings for the status values, but you could do something more elegant).

Edit:

As several users have pointed out, make sure that you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` after modifying you database values. Also if you are pulling your data from a remote server, make sure you have updated the upvote/downvote values before you do the reload, (or at least properly merge remote data with your local data).

Comment: Does this answer the question? I'm not really sure.

Comment: His issue is not a code problem its a data architecture problem. I could add the code to have the view show based on the status i mentioned, but that's fairly trivial. The problem is that Bargain23 is not maintaining a record of the button state other than the UI, so when the UI triggers a redraw, he loses the action.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about. There are some problem with the code too.

Comment: That part of the code is missing, (where he reloads the data), so I can't make an assumption as to whether that is the problem. If he uses my architecture description, his code will work as he intends. The fact that the data is reset to clean state tells me that he is probably doing that correctly.

Comment: Then please add proper comment to clarify the question first.

Comment: @Jlange Doesn't the boolean `hasReacted` perform that function, no?

Comment: No, the `hasReacted` appears to just enable/disable the buttons, it does not record what action was actually performed. In this case a boolean is not sufficient to record the possible scenarios and a more robust value is required. (I guess they could use null, but I would recommend against that)